# How can I get post data when adding a product to cart?

Tags: forms, event-observer

Tested and searched on this.. believe me.

I have created a form which when submitted adds a specific product to the cart. An input will look like this for example:

```
<input id="home:email" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" type="text" size="40" maxlength="60" title="email" name="home[email]" />
```

I am now trying to get that form's data in my observer (in a custom module). The event I thought best to hook onto is checkout_cart_add_product_complete as it provides:

```
array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this→getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
```

I've tried lots of different variations but cannot return the form's data in my observer function, e.g.

```
// none of these work
$data = $observer->getRequest()->getPost('home', array());
$data = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getPost('home', array());
$data = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getPost('home', array());
$data = $observer->getRequest()->getParams();
$data = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getParams();
$data = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Can anyone suggest how i do this or if there are any alternative approaches? Many thanks_g

..and for absolute clarification here's the form:

```
<?php
// creates add to cart submit url
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(1);
$add2cartUrl = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);
$add2cartUrl = substr_replace($add2cartUrl, '?', -1, 1);
$options_arr = array('options[-5071]' => 1)
foreach($options_arr as $idx => $val) $optsSuffix_arr[] = $idx.'='.$val;
$add2cartUrl .= implode('&',$optsSuffix_arr);
// e.g. $add2cartUrl outputs: http://mywebsite.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2FydHNob3BkaXJlY3QuY28udWs‌​vc29mdHdhcmUtbWFnZW50bzIv/product/1/form_key/Hs2WoFBfnJtChfwN?options[-5071]=1
?>
<form class="create-account" name="home-create-account" id="home-create-account">
<input type="hidden" name="product" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
<div class="input-box">
    <input id="home:email" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" type="text" size="40" maxlength="60" title="email" name="home[email]" />
</div>
<fieldset class="add-to-cart-box">
<div class="add-to-cart">
<button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $add2cartUrl ?>')" title="Click Here" type="button">
<span>
<span style="text-transform:uppercase;">Click Here</span>
</span>
</button>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: In your observer method try log/var_dump the entire $_POST array or if you can use something like XDebug and check if the variable exists at all($_POST['home']['email'].

Comment: I just tried this but as suspected it returned an empty array.. I think this is because magento has its own way of handling posted data. For example when saving billing in one page checkout (with controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling) this is used to retrieve the form data: `$observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());` so not entirely sure why I can't use `$observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getPost('home', array());`

Comment: Ok, when you click add to cart, can you observe the parameters passed to the server by using some tool like  firebug or chrome developer tools.

Comment: I have both firebug and the chrome developer tool. At which point and where will I be able to see such information?_

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/chrome-dev-tools-networking-and-the-console/

Comment: Maybe your html form not correct, switch to default magento theme and test it

Comment: @Evgeni Ivanov - I can't see any parameters being passed. This is the url it posts to `http://mywebsite.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2FydHNob3BkaXJlY3QuY28udWsvc29mdHdhcmUtbWFnZW50bzIv/product/1/form_key/Hs2WoFBfnJtChfwN?options[-5071]=1`. My understanding is that the form action should be `post` rather than `get`.

Comment: Yes, i just checked the code in Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction().It uses $this->getRequest()->getParams()($_GET params). So i guess you should append the ['home']['email'] to the url and than use $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getParam('email').

Comment: I just saw something in your form. You haven't explicitly specified method (which by default is GET http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)

Comment: Really want to upvote you for informing me about the default form method being GET (thought it was POST) but I don't have enough reputation.. I'll definitely log this and come back and do that when I have enough.. that's one reason to upvote me I guess. So just a big thanks.. for now!_g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just wanted to show how I got to the solution.. it always seems so obvious afterwards..

Because I specified my button like this:

```
<button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $add2cartUrl ?>')" title="Click Here" type="button">
```

Rather than as `type="submit"` (and no `onclick` javascript event) the form was never submitting but just sending to that location - so I couldn't get any data in the form. Thanks to Evgeni Ivanov for stating that the default form action is GET - I had previously thought this to be POST. So after specifying this in my form like so (where `$add2cartUrl` is shown above in the question):

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $add2cartUrl ?>" class="create-account" name="home-create-account" id="home-create-account">
```

I was then able to pull through the POST data using the event `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` and got the data I required with:

```
$data = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getPost('home', array());
```

Sincerest thanks to all contributers and anyone looking to do something similar will do well to have a quick run through this
_g

Answer (score 3):

This would work,

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Comment: Yes, this code helps to read Request Params. I've developed complex configurable product page where few Html inputs (not options or attributes) are needed to pass to cart page. My code can calculate the cart amount successfully. But, when I refresh the cart page, the request params become NULL and the calculated amount becomes wrong. How and where should I keep those request params so that it can be persistent in other steps.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is works, compare with it. 
**/app/code/local/Some/Module/etc/config.xml**

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
            <observers>
                <some_module>
                    <class>Some_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>checkoutCartAddProductComplete</method>
                </some_module>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

**/app/code/local/Some/Module/Model/Observer.php**

```
public function checkoutCartAddProductComplete($observer){
    Mage::log($observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getPost());
    Mage::log(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost());
}
```

If it does not help you, switch the magento default theme. Make sure your post data is beeing sent to server using firebug.

Comment: Yeah - the details in config.xml and observer.php are the same - how are you composing the form? thanks_g

Comment: Switch to magento default theme, and test it again

Comment: tried this to no avail and just added my form code above.. interested to see how yours compares_

Comment: You customized Magento add to cart form very different from standard magento logic, see code of default theme (/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml), your code seems incorrect.

Comment: That definitely works but I'm always interested in suggestions if you have them. the view.phtml file relies on the magento method `getSubmitUrl` which I was unable to call in my module template file and as I was using options became more complex. I did a lot of looking on this and used this - http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring - as a reference. Look again at how I changed the form and it probably looks a lot more like the standard magento logic you talk of. Many thanks_g